# "Vocal captcha" for robots on the phone?

Tags: human-like, voice-recognition, computational-linguistics

With all the Google I/O stuff coming out, how can I verify that I have an actual human on the phone using only voice? Are there still vocal things humans can, but robots can't do?

Conditions: the person on the phone is a stranger (so personal questions won't work), and the verification must be voice only.

(Also, I understand Google Duplex may be just an overhyped demo that will turn out to flop like the Pixel Buds. But eventually such a bot would be created, right? If so, what's the best verification?)

Answer (score 1):

your question is a very similar to "turing-test". you could narrate a simple story and ask questions based on that , considering the state-of-art algorithms in "question-answering" are still far beyond human skills.